# Installable onOpen trigger set by script will not run in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I made an installable onOpen trigger in one script which is bound to a spreadsheet and it creates a trigger as desired. The code I used to create the trigger was:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('customOnOpen').forSpreadsheet(ss).onOpen().create();
```

This creates the following trigger:

[image: auto created trigger]

But this trigger doesn't fire when the spreadsheet is opened.

I discovered that if I delete the trigger and create it by hand I get this trigger:

[image: manually created trigger]

You can see that the second trigger is deployed from head. I am not sure of the difference in this contect as I am not making a web App. It's just code that runs for the spreadsheet. Anyway the manually installed trigger works. I could not see a way to create the deploy from head trigger via Apps script code.

Help :)))

Comment: Have you checked [the restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for installable triggers?

Comment: Thanks Alex, No I hadn't but I have now and I don't see anything in the restrictions that would cause this.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the case: (1) created simple **customOnOpen** function, (2) created **installCustomTrigger** and included your code, where `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` (3) run it (4) allow permissions for "me" and (5) reopen. It works!